# Multithreading - why private member variable shared?

Tags: java, multithreading

The running of the following code outputs 6,7,8 at different times. I am not sure why. Each of the threads have count variable which is private. Then how are  they sharing the same variable?

```
public class ThreadSafety {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ProcessingThread pt = new ProcessingThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(pt, "t1");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(pt, "t2");
        t2.start();
        //wait for threads to finish processing
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Processing count="+pt.getCount());
    }

}

class ProcessingThread implements Runnable{
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            processSomething(i);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    private void processSomething(int i) {
        // processing some job
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `private` means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two threads, but a single object. Of course those threads will share all of the variables of the single object. If you created 2 `ProcessingThread` objects and gave both threads their own instance, this wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

A new Thread when started will only have its own execution context. It wont create a copy of objects and won't maintain its own memory space. It will instead share the heap memory.

In your case, you had created a object on heap and passed the same object reference to two threads. while two threads are being executed simultaneously, they are sharing the same object which arises a race condition while accessing count variable and performing count++. This is causing inconsistent in your output.

If you are sharing same object and like to see the result constantly as 8, put count++ in synchronized block as below

```
public void run() {
    for(int i=1; i< 5; i++){
        processSomething(i);
        synchronized(this) {
        count++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are sharing the object out of which you don't want to share particular object variable, then declare it as thread local.